Escaping quotes in Python subprocesses for Windows
I'm trying to terminate a Python program that uses many threads on its own.
If I'm not mistaken, just sys.exit() works fine.
However, to guard against my many mistakes, including losing references to threads, I tried the following:
subprocess.Popen(['start', 'cmd.exe', '/c', f'timeout 5&taskkill /f /fi "PID eq {os.getppid()}"'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

I thought it was a problem with escaping the quotes, so I tried several things but failed. I gave up and did the following and it worked perfectly.
with open('exit_self.bat', 'w') as file:
  file.write(f'timeout 5&taskkill /f /fi "PID eq {os.getppid()}"&del exit_self.bat')
subprocess.Popen(['start', 'cmd.exe', '/c', 'exit_self.bat'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

How can I do it without temp files? What did I miss? For reference, I used /k instead of /c option of cmd.exe to leave the window and check the error message in the window, it is as follows:
Waiting for 0 seconds, press a key to continue ...
ERROR: Invalid argument/option - 'eq'.
Type "TASKKILL /?" for usage.

I'm not sure if it will help, but I added echo to see the syntax of the command being executed:
subprocess.Popen(['start', 'cmd.exe', '/k', 'echo', f'timeout 5&taskkill /f /fi "PID eq {os.getppid()}"'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

The result is:
"timeout 5&taskkill /f /fi \"PID eq 3988\""


It's not clear whether these are Python threads you started yourself or from another program. In the first case, interrupting all running threads at exit was my solution. I had also tried to make them daemon threads, but that caused a lot of other problems.

They are processes not threads.

I agree. My goal is to terminate the thread normally. It is only for extreme situations where thread management is impossible due to memory modification, crack attempts, DDos, etc.

Yes, my post omits the code for the thread. I'm trying to create it elsewhere and terminate it properly, but this is just in case I make a mistake.

From subprocess.Popen:

args should be a sequence of program arguments or else a single string or path-like object.

Run notepad.exe and be sure to not type in its window so "Untitled - Notepad" is the title.  I'm using WINDOWTITLE eq Untitled* so I don't have to look up the PID. Use a single string for the command.  This will open a window, countdown, and kill Notepad.  Note that the entire /c parameter must be quoted so it is passed to the second command window.
import subprocess
import time

p = subprocess.Popen('start cmd.exe /c "timeout 5&taskkill /f /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq Untitled*""', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
for i in range(3):
    print(str(i) * 10)
    time.sleep(1)


Output in original command window showing parallel work.  Another cmd window opens with the countdown.  Notepad was killed 2 seconds after 2222222222 printed due to the 5 second total timeout before taskkill:
0000000000
1111111111
2222222222


Thanks, I just needed a new console window to visually confirm that a force quit operation was in progress.

@enoeht Please accept the answer if this was helpful :)

Oh, sorry, I'm still looking for a way to use start cmd.exe for the same reason as above.

@enoeht You get the error message from the communicate portion of the code and you can still add "start cmd.exe /k" to the beginning of the string (or ['start','cmd.exe','/k'] to the start of the list) if you want to see the window.

communicate causes a process block. As in the text, I declared it to run after 5 seconds, and in the meantime, I tried to do normal thread cleanup. If the block occurs, I can't use it.

@enoeht So don’t use it. Add the start back in as I commented if you want a window.  You’re starting a new process so it runs whether you wait for it or not. My answer does show you how to get it to work properly

I try this without communicate: subprocess.Popen(f'start cmd.exe /k timeout 5&taskkill /f /fi "PID eq {os.getpid()}"', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE). But this force quits without waiting 5 seconds. What did I miss?

@enoeht start cmd.exe immediately returns after it spawns cmd.exe, then runs taskkill.  I've updated the question with a complete example that shows you can do other things and the target is killed after 5 seconds.  start cmd is not needed.

Again, I need the external window to be open for 5 seconds.

@enoeht I thought you opened the window just to see that it was working.  The task gets killed in 5 seconds and you can do other things while waiting.

@enoeht Now a countdown window opens. Note extra quotes around the /c parameter so it is all passed to the 2nd cmd window.

I am so amazed and grateful that you have been so kind to me for so long. My foolishness has been bothering you for so long.
